# How to solve an integral in two dummy variables if both variables are forced to be the same?

Tags: integration, expected-value, mathematical-astronomy

What happens to a general integral of this form in two dummy variables, $x$ and $y$
\begin{equation}
\langle \int\int f(x)g^*(y) dxdy \rangle
\end{equation}
if the expectation product $\langle f(x)g^*(y) \rangle $ = 0 for $x \neq y$?

*For context*, I am trying to understand how Equation (1-3) of [Synthesis Imaging in Radio Astronomy II](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1999ASPC..180.....T) (Chapter 2), given below
\begin{equation}
        V_\nu(r_1,r_2) = \langle \int \int \varepsilon_\nu (R_1) \varepsilon^*_\nu(R_2)
        \frac{e^{2\pi i \nu |R_1 - r_1|/c}}{|R_1 - r_1|}  \frac{e^{2\pi i \nu |R_2 - r_2|/c}}{|R_2 - r_2|} dS_1 dS_2 \rangle
    \end{equation}
can be simplified into
\begin{equation}
        V_\nu(r_1,r_2) = \int \langle |\varepsilon_\nu (R)^2| \rangle |R^2|
        \frac{e^{2\pi i \nu |R - r_1|/c}}{|R - r_1|}  \frac{e^{2\pi i \nu |R - r_2|/c}}{|R - r_2|} dS .
    \end{equation}
when $R_1\neq R_2$.

Here $\varepsilon$ is the surface brightness distribution of sources at $R_1$ and $R_2$, $r_1$ and $r_2$ are two points where the sources are observed, and $dS$ is the unit area on an imaginary celestial sphere.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "expectation product"?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I am sorry, I meant the expectation of the product, i.e., $\langle f(x)g^*(y)\rangle$.

Comment: Okay then, expectation over what? Expectations are weighted sums over variables (particularly when weighted by probability). In the integral expression, the only variables are $f, g$. What are you summing over?  What sort of weighting are you doing? In the product, are you still summing over $f$ and/or $g$ with the same weightings, is it summing over $x$ and/or $y$?